# Sort a Parquet file externally by multiple columns

Tags: gratis, open-source, data

### Problem

I have a Parquet file that is **much larger than my memory** and would like to **sort it according to two columns**.

Specifically let's say I have 64GB of memory, a 1TB Parquet file with the columns `user_id` (string) and `timestamp` (integer) which I'd like sorted, in that order.

### Requirements

The solution must be able to

- work on a locally stored file
- handle the data with the limited available memory
- be robust in that I can be sure it won't run out of memory or stall

The solution should be FOSS, though non-FOSS recommendations would also be appreciated.

Preferred, but not required

- Solution that finishes in a reasonable time (let's say a couple of days *at most*)
- Output the sorted data to Parquet

The ideal solution would use Python, but at this point, I'm very happy to use absolutely any technology.

### What I've tried

[Dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376425/dask-dataframe-equivalent-of-pandas-dataframe-sort-values)

- Does not natively support sorting by two columns
- Memory usage often just blows up with bigger data (potentially solvable)

[Vaex](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.dataframe.DataFrame.sort)

- Very low CPU utilization, seemed to be very slow
- I had problems with Parquet IO, Vaex seemed to simply stall.
- Admittedly, the reasons above are a bit vague as I haven't tried Vaex enough. If you think Vaex might be up for the task, then that could still be the answer.

Comment: Have you think about using `hive` tables (if you have `hadoop` of course)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I do not have `hadoop`, but I might consider looking into that option, if nothing else crops up. Feel free to answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution about your case is to use external software. My idea is to use Hive with Parquet tables and create the sort there.

[Here](http://www.hadooplessons.info/2017/08/how-to-create-hive-table-for-parquet-file.html) you can find sample instruction how to create table for Parquet. You can also check [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303371/can-we-load-parquet-file-into-hive-directly) in Stack Overflow about load the data directly from Parquet file.

[Here](https://www.educba.com/hive-order-by/) you will find how to build statement with sort by column. [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy) you will see some detailed documentation.

But generally the command will be something like:

```
select * from table order by col1,col2;
```

This solution can work with huge tables because it split the work in jobs which deal with much smaller data than the source file/table.